# Are types 'int' or 'long', 'char', etc. always signed in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, unsigned, signed

I always knew I had signed values when I used `int` or `long`, `char`, `short`, etc. in C and C++ development. By the way, depending on the compiler or OS, what happens when the default signedness of these types becomes unsigned?  I'm inquiring because I've never seen a reference to this in a paper or a book, and I don't know it.

Comment: What is the "default value"? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli char is not a signed type.

Comment: Integer types are signed by default, only the character types are unspecified https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: `char` can be either `signed` or `unsigned` (implementation defined) and is a distinct type from `unsigned char` and `signed char`; see [Character types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types)

Comment: `char` can be unsigned on some platforms, but usually it is signed. Everything else is signed.

Comment: `char` variables can be signed or unsigned: it's implementation dependent. (Microsoft's C compiler lets you control this with a compiler option). The original ANSI C required that character constants be non-negative, but I can't find any such restriction in the current standard.

Comment: @chux: Re “C offers no definition to create a negative constant”: Try `printf("%d\n", '\xff');` and `enum { foo = -37 }; printf("%d\n", foo);`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 2 fine counter examples.

Comment: Related: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/12149471)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Types `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` are all signed unless explicitly qualified as `unsigned`.  Note that `short` and `long` are actually qualifiers themselves and the type `int` is implicit if omitted.

Type `char` is special: it is different from type `signed char`, which obviously is signed and from type `unsigned char`, which is not.  Depending on the platform and compiler settings, type `char` may be signed or unsigned. You can test this by comparing the value of the macro `CHAR_MIN` defined in `<limits.h>` to `0` or by casting `-1` as `(char)` and testing if it stays negative.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    if ((char)-1 < 0) {
        /* most common case */
        printf("char is signed, range is %d..%d\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
    } else
    if (sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)) {
        /* corner case, for some DSP systems */
        /* char type is the same as unsigned int */
        printf("char is unsigned, range is %u..%u\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
    } else {
        /* common case, enabled with -funsigned-char for gcc and clang */
        /* char values and constants will promote to int */
        printf("char is unsigned, range is %d..%d\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you cannot use the above tests for preprocessing, but the constants defined in `<limits.h>` can be used in preprocessor expressions:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
#if CHAR_MIN < 0
    printf("char is signed, range is %d..%d\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
#elif CHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX
    printf("char is unsigned, range is %u..%u\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
#else
    printf("char is unsigned, range is %d..%d\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

This also works in C++, but there is a more idiomatic way to test it using `std::is_signed_v<char>`.

Comment: Or `std::is_signed_v<char>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: sure, answer amended.

Comment: ... or `(char)-1 < (char)0`

Comment: @chqrlie Corner case: for those pesky `char` as wide as `int/unsigned`, `printf(", range is %d..%d\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);` needs `printf(", range is %u..%u\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);` when `char` is _unsigned_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `printf(", range is %d..%u\n", (int)CHAR_MIN, (unsigned)CHAR_MAX);` will work.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: corner case tested and explained, without casts

Comment: @pts: good point, answer amended with both methods

Comment: @IanAbbott: interesting approach, but I prefer to use as few casts as possible.

Comment: I'd expect to print `CHAR_MIN` using `"%d"` is always OK.

Comment: At the risk of language lawyering, I'd also assert `printf("%u\n", CHAR_MAX);` is also always OK given "value is representable in both" C23dr § 7.16.1.1 2.

Comment: IOWs, I assert `printf("char is unsigned, range is %d..%u\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);` is always good.

Comment: Warning: language-lawyer speaking. `CHAR_MIN` is representable as an `int`, but its type may be `unsigned int` in the pathological case where `char` is unsigned and `sizeof(unsigned) == 1`. Passing an `unsigned int` for `%d` is undefined behavior until C17 and defined if the value is representable in both types only as of C23.  This change is rooted in common sense, but comes a bit late.  The case of `%u` for `CHAR_MAX` is different yet even more compelling as the behavior is undefined under C17 and before for all other architectures.

Comment: The change in C23dr is only possible because it gets rid of non 2's complement representations of signed integer types.